# UIKit and Cocos2d in one application

Tags: iphone, uikit, uiviewcontroller, cocos2d-iphone

i've a huge problem..
I want to use both cocos2d and UIkit frameworks in one application, here is the scenario:
user log in, via UIkit, then play a game written in cocos2d, and after that the actual uikit ordinary application starts. the problem is that, after starting cocos game, i'm unable to return to uikit view-based application. does anybody have idea how to make it?
Thanks for any help

mapedd

Comment: I've used the CCUIViewWrapper class several times to achieve what you are looking to do. There are several other ways to achieve this but this has worked best for me. [http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/6889](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/6889)